# Routing: How can I ignore a parameter in route definition?

Tags: config, routes, routing, regex

I'm trying to route users to a "locations" structure entry that normally has a URL structure that looks like: `locations/<slug>`

My client wants to use the structure of links from their old site to preserve SEO and wants to have the URL structure of: `locations/<state>/<slug>` where state is a 2 letter string. So, I'm trying to set up a route rule that just ignores the  parameter and redirects to the regular route.

In routes.php I have the following rule:

`'locations/<state:[a-z]{2}>/<slug:{slug}>' => 'locations/<slug>'`

But when I try to hit a route (for example `locations/ca/slug-name`) I get an InvalidRouteException and an error message saying:

Unable to resolve the request "locations/slug-name"

So it looks like it's stripping out the state parameter successfully but I'm not sure why `locations/slug-name` isn't recognized as a valid route.

Is there something I'm missing? Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you might be trying to blend Craft/Yii routing with Rewrites (if you're coming from an Apache background).

I believe what Craft interprets this as is an attempt to map a request to `locations/or/my-entry-slug` to the `<slug>` (literal) action of the `locations` controller (which doesn't exist).

If you just want to render a template for these entries, you can set up your route like this:

```
'locations/<state:[a-z]{2}>/<slug:{slug}>' => ['template' => 'locations/entry']
```

This way, you'll get a `state` and `slug` variable in the `templates/locations/entry.twig` template, with which you can look up the Locations Entry you want.

To troubleshoot further, we might need a bit more information about how your Locations Section is set up, and the goals for the route!

> If you're just looking to capture and redirect legacy URLs, be sure and [check out the Retour plugin](https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-retour).
>
> Additionally (and for anyone who finds this in the future), I'd recommend reviewing the [advanced routing](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/routing.html#advanced-routing-with-url-rules) docs.

Comment: Thank you! I had tried the `['template' => 'path']` method before but was trying to pass the slug in directly instead of pointing to the generic entry and loading the specific entry there. This worked perfectly!